# Return Coordinate on Click Grid Panel

Tags: java, javafx, mouseevent, coordinates, nodes

I created an application which generates a board with a grid pattern, consisting of nodes which hold square objects in javaFX, using GridPanel. Below is the current output:

[image]

I want to know how to return the coordinate of a node, after CLICKING on the node. I am aware I have to use an action listener of sorts, but I'm not entirely familiar when it comes to having node coordinates.

Below is the current source code, thank you very much.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MainApp extends Application {

    private final double windowWidth = 1000;
    private final double windowHeight = 1000;

    /*n is amount of cells per row
      m is amount of cells per column*/
    private final int n = 50;
    private final int m = 50;

    double gridWidth = windowWidth / n;
    double gridHeight = windowHeight / m;

    MyNode[][] playfield = new MyNode[n][m];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        Group root = new Group();

        // initialize playfield
        for( int i=0; i < n; i++) {
            for( int j=0; j < m; j++) {

                // create node
                MyNode node = new MyNode( i * gridWidth, j * gridHeight, gridWidth, gridHeight);

                // add node to group
                root.getChildren().add( node);

                // add to playfield for further reference using an array
                playfield[i][j] = node;

            }
        }

        Scene scene = new Scene( root, windowWidth, windowHeight);

        primaryStage.setScene( scene);
        primaryStage.show();
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.sizeToScene();
    }

    public static class MyNode extends StackPane {

        public MyNode(double x, double y, double width, double height) {

            // create rectangle
            Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle( width, height);
            rectangle.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
            rectangle.setFill(Color.LIGHTGREEN);

            // set position
            setTranslateX(x);
            setTranslateY(y);

            getChildren().addAll(rectangle);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you set the `onMouseClicked` handler you can get the coordinates, either directly or by querying the `MouseEvent`.

Comment: https://github.com/sedj601/ConwaysGameOfLife/tree/master/src/conwaysgameoflife

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add mouse event handler to root :

```
  root.setOnMousePressed(e->mousePressedOnRoot(e));
```

Where `mousePressedOnRoot(e)` is defined as

```
  private void mousePressedOnRoot(MouseEvent e) {
    System.out.println("mouse pressed on (x-y): "+e.getSceneX()+"-"+e.getSceneY());
  }
```

**Edit:** alternatively you can add mouse event handler to each `MyNode` instance by adding `setOnMousePressed(e->mousePressedOnNode(e));`  to its constructor.

and add the method:

```
 private void mousePressedOnNode(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("mouse pressed on (x-y): "+e.getSceneX()+"-"+e.getSceneY());
 }
```

If you need the coordinates within the clicked node use `e.getX()` and `e.getY()`

Comment: This code works, but it is returning the coordinates of the actual screen instead of the node that im currently selecting.

Comment: See my edit. I am not sure what exactly you need, you may want to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31148690/get-real-position-of-a-node-in-javafx)